# unable to remove range of items in a list

Tags: list, c#-4.0, sorting, generic-list

I am setting the items which i want to Remove from list as null and then sorting list through IComparable method CompareTo so that null items would be at the top ... then using RemoveRange function on list but unable to so so ... i see no problem in following code:

```
      try
      {
          foreach (Invoice item in inv)
          {
              if (item.qty == 0)
              {
                  item.CustomerName = null;
                  item.qty = 0;
                  i++;
              }
          }
          inv.Sort();
          inv.RemoveRange(0, i);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
```

## }

```
        #region IComparable<Invoice> Members

    public int CompareTo(Invoice other)
    {
        return this.CustomerName.CompareTo(other.CustomerName);
    }

    #endregion
```

error occurs at inv.RemoveRange(0,i); saying that :Failed to compare two elemets in array

Why is it so??

Comment: `null.CompareTo(null)` ?

Comment: oh yes! ... how do i get away with the problem then?

Comment: wont the sort method just put the items with null on top of list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int CompareTo(Invoice other)
    {
    if (other == null || other.CustomerName == null) return 1;
    if (this.CustomerName == null) return -1;

    return this.CustomerName.CompareTo(other.CustomerName);
    }
```

or

```
public int CompareTo(Invoice other)
        {
        //if other Invoide is null, instance is bigger.
        if (other == null) return 1;
        if (this.CustomerName == null) {
           //if both CustomerName are null, instance equals other. Of only instance CustomerName is null, other is bigger.
           return other.CustomerName == null ? 0 : -1;
        }
        //if other.CustomerName is null (and instance.CustomerName is not null), instance is bigger.
        if (other.CustomerName == null) return 1;

        //both CustomerName are not null, call basic string.CompareTo
        return this.CustomerName.CompareTo(other.CustomerName);
        }
```

Comment: Also, { return this.qty.CompareTo(other.qty); } would do the task if item.qty=0; :) ... Thanks

Comment: Yes. If your business logic is respected, just do it ;)